# On mouse hover of first menu,other menu will getting different fonts in Firefox Only

Tags: html, firefox

In my code,i have added mouse hover for all menus,which add background color blue.Mouse hover is working fine in all browsers.But in Firefox ,when i hover the mouse on first menu,fonts of other menus get changed.I googled lots things but seem it not working..can i get help??

[image]

[image]

Below is HTML code:

```
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <input class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar" value="humburger" type="button">



                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="/Images/enterprise_nav_globalnav_usaalogo.svg" class="img-responsive logo-img" alt="USSA"></a>
            </div>
            <div id="myNavbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav font-bold">
                    <li class="dropdown provider-menu">
                        <a id="hypProviderHome">ACCOUNT</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-content">
                             <a id="hypAddProvider" href="AccountUpdate.aspx">Update Account Information</a>
                             <a id="hypRegisteredProvider" href="ProviderList.aspx">Update Provider Information</a>
                             <a id="hypNewProvider" href="NewProvider.aspx">Register New Provider</a>
                             <a id="hypResetPassword" href="../Account/ChangePassword.aspx">Change Password</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="provider-menu"><a id="hypHome" href="ProviderHome.aspx">HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="provider-menu"><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                    <li class="provider-menu"><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="provider-menu">
                        <a id="lnkLogOff" class="logoff" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$lnkLogOff','')">LOGOFF</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>


        </div>
    </nav>                                                                                                    CSS for same:.provider-menu:hover {
    background-color: #3071AF;
}

li.provider-menu {
    display: inline-block;
}


.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.provider-menu:hover .dropdown-content {
        display: block;
    }                                                                                                     The sub menu is visible only for Account Menu not for all.Problem is when i hover mouse on Account menu that time all other menus getting different fonts.This issue is only on Firefox .And font is declared only for body tag which is  font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
```

Comment: If you don't share your code we can't help you. I assume the error is in the submenu that the typography is different. But you need to share a working example to allow us to help you. Otherwise this should be closed as offtopic

Comment: Below is HTML code:

Comment: i have updated question with my HTML and CSS code..i am new on stack overflow forum..please help me in that

Comment: Can any one help me on above issue.Appreciate your help

Comment: @ Gurunath Bhopale please, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Set font family to the elements

```
.dropdown-content a {
    font-family: 'Your font', Arial, sans-serif ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @marcos..already i have set the font to  font-family: "Gotham",Arial,sans-serif;

Comment: sorry for previous comment.i have already set font to font-family: "Gotham",Arial,sans-serif;  Issue comes when i hover mouse on Account menu,then other menu likes Home,About and Contact getting different fonts,means it is getting blur text.my code is simple...is it need to add reset.css or moderize.css for this?

Comment: I don't know, you need to provide us a working example. Read stackoverflow rules: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve